# enable button when fileupload has file

Tags: asp.net, button

I have two image button is disable, I wish to enable it when there is a file in fileupload control. I search through the online resources they will have a button. But how can I do it when user selected a file and both image button will be prompt?
you answer and comment will be appreaciated.

code below is javascript code.

```
<script>
        function fnCallback() {
            $("#ImageButton2").show();
        } 
</script>
```

follow by asp.net code.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" onChange="fnCallback();"/>

<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Width="20px" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/Image/save-btn.png" style="display:none;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from client side,

By calling a javascript function on filecontrol `onChange` event

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" onChange='fnCallback();' />
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" style="display:none;"
  ImageUrl="~/imagePath"  />
```

---

```
function fnCallback() {
    // $("#ImageButton1").show(); In jQuery
    document.getElementById("ImageButton1").style.display = "block"; // In JavaScript
 }
```

Comment: @LstPatrick : what error you getting ?? have you included jQuery lib ?

Comment: I am kinda new to this.. no error occur... just being filter the function

Comment: put a alert in `fnCallback()` and see if alert occurs ?

Comment: the alert do appear. but I didnt see the image button

Answer (score 0):

```
  function importMember(courseSelectImport,value){ 
    if ( courseSelectImport && value) {
      jQuery('#csvsubmite').attr('disabled',false);
      jQuery( '#csvsubmite' ).addClass( "importbtn" );
    } else {
       jQuery('#csvsubmite').attr('disabled',true);
       jQuery('#csvsubmite' ).removeClass( "importbtn" );
    }
  }
  jQuery('input:file').change(function(){
    let value = jQuery(this).val();
    let courseSelectImport = jQuery('#courseSelectImport').val(); 
    importMember(courseSelectImport,value);
  });

  jQuery('#courseSelectImport').on('change',function(){
    let courseSelectImport = jQuery(this).val();
    let fileVal = jQuery('input:file').val();
    importMember(courseSelectImport,fileVal);
  });


<label class="col-md-4 mb-0 text-right">Course</label>
 <select name="courseSelectImport" id="courseSelectImport" class="custom-select">
  <option value="">All</option>
</select>
<input type='file' name='membercsv' accept=".csv">
<input type='submit' name='submit' id="csvsubmite" value='Import'  disabled>
```